# Endpoint Error With Multiple IPs

Tags: wcf

I am having a problem when deploying my WCF service. Locally it works fine, but on our test server we have a number of different services setup in IIS, all with different IPs, say:

192.168.0.10  <--- Default IP
192.168.0.11
192.168.0.12  <--- My webservice IP

when I try to browse to http://192.168.0.12/mysevervice.svc all is ok. However if I add it to the WCF test client it detects the service ok, but when I try and invoke a service method it does a dns lookup and tries I get an error like the following:

There was no endpoint listening at http://pcname/mysevervice.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the pertinent sections of your host and client config files.

Comment: If anyone else has this problem the solution was to blank out the dns

          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that 'pcname' can be resolved from your client PC.  You may notice that when you browse out to your svc file through: [Http://SomeIPAddress/Service.svc](http://Http://SomeIPAddress/Service.svc) that the WCF service shows the machine name for downloading the WSDL.

I would imagine that if you are generating the client through VS than the machine name is being plugged in to the client, and not the IP Address. Check your app.config to make sure your URLs are all correct.